# In chef solo, how to use a common cookbook into other cookbooks

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have lots of common attributes across cookbooks. 
After researching I found the correct way (for my use case) is to use a common cookbook. But since I am new to chef world, I am not able to figure out how to use one.

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad a question for StackOverflow but you can find the introductory Chef tutorials at learn.chef.io which covers the basics of creating cookbooks. Beyond that really all you need to know for this is that cookbooks can depend on each other much like libraries in other languages, via the `depends` keyword in the `metadata.rb` file. You can find more about using the `metadata.rb` file in both the tutorials and Chef documentation.